# Can this shape be drawn in css?

Tags: html, css, shapes, nav, css-shapes

I am struggling currently with creating this effect on my navbar, effectively it will curve down like this but I've had a look everywhere on the web and can't seem to find anything on how to re-create this in css (or if its even possible) If anyone could point me in the right direction or give me some advice on how to achieve this effect it would be greaty appreciated.

Here's the shape:
 [image: http://i.imgur.com/EaIK8J0.png]

Comment: You will probably want to do it in SVG instead of CSS: https://sarasoueidan.com/blog/css-svg-clipping/

Answer (score 1):

You can use this tool: http://bennettfeely.com/clippy/ or try clipping path by SVG